# Unexpected symbol in "if"

Tags: r

I'm programming (using R) in order to calculate the expected time of life of a system.
It has 2 computers and 1 processor, the systems works when at least 1 computer and the processor works.

Keeping that in mind, i've tried to calculate the expected life by programming the following lines, but i couldn't calculate it because i made an error . Can someone tell me what can i do to fix that error and make the code work? Any idea of why that is happening?.

Thanks a lot!

```
life<-function(tfailC,tfailP,tfailC1, tfailC2,ttotalfail){
n<-1000
tfailC1<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailC2<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailP<-runif(n, min=0, max=1500)
tfailC=0
ttotalfail=0
for (i in 1:n) {

if
tfailC1>tfailC2 #error:Error: unexpected symbol in:"if tfailC1"
tfailC<-tfailC1
else
 tfailC<-tfailC2

if tfailC>tfailP
 ttotalfail<-tfailC
 else
ttotalfail<-tfailP
 }
  }return(ttotalfail)
```

Comment: This isn't valid R syntax. It should look like `if (tfailC1>tfailC) {tfailC<-tfailC1} else {tfailC<-tfailC2}`. The parens are required for the `if`

Comment: Study `help("if")`.

Comment: Thanks!, adding the parentheses and braces definetly solved the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
life<-function(tfailP,tfailC1, tfailC2){
  tfailC <- pmax(tfailC1,tfailC2)
  ttotalfail <- pmax(tfailC,tfailP)
  return(ttotalfail)
}

#Test function below
n<-1000
tfailC1<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailC2<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailP<-runif(n, min=0, max=1500)

life(tfailP,tfailC1,tfailC2)
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked too!

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as useful if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! if someone is interested here goes the code that actually works:

```
set.seed(1)
life<-function(n){
n
tfailC1<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailC2<-runif(n, min=0, max=500)
tfailP<-runif(n, min=0, max=1500)
tfailC=0
ttotalfail=0
for (i in 1:n) {

 if
 (tfailC1>tfailC2)
 {tfailC<-tfailC1}
 else
 {tfailC<-tfailC2}

if (tfailC>tfailP)

{ttotalfail<-tfailP}
else
{ttotalfail<-tfailC}
 }
 return(ttotalfail)
 }
```